# What did Maxine mean when she told Jill the Doctor would be coming back?

Tags: dialogue, charlies-angels

In the 1976 *Charlie's Angels* Episode 'Angels in Chains', when Jill (Farrah Fawcett) is being taken out of the Prison Sick Bay by the Tough Female Guard Maxine (Mary Woronov) and then knocks the Signing In and Out Sheet off the Table and Maxine tells Jill that if she doesn't pick it up the Doctor would be coming back only this time it wouldn't be for Stomach Cramps.

What exactly did she mean?

Answer (score 1):

It's a threat to **hurt Jill** (thus needing the doctor again) if she doesn't comply and pick up the signing log.

No need to read any more into it than that.